# SQL do some code, after committing changes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers, commit

After adding new row to the table, and saving changes, 
I want to call another function (automatically) which does some changes in another table.

I have no idea, how to make trigger or something like that, which could react on table save.

If it is possible, can someone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
 CREATE TRIGGER
```

which is called on UPDATE or INSERT. There are some examples at - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.90).aspx